# c++ How to search for a name or address from a file?

Tags: c++

I've a file including names and addresses to a Person Registry.
First I add the persons in my personArray, then I print them and finally Delete them.
So far, it works just fine.

Now Im trying to implement a Search()-function, where I can either find the name or the address of a person.
I call this in main()-function like this:

```
void SearchForPerson(PersonReg personReg)
{
    Person *x1 = personReg.SearchForPerson("Jolina", nullptr);
    Person *x2 = personReg.SearchForPerson("Olle", x1);
}
```

And I will be able to keep searcing for the Persons like this: (string search, pointer to the previous hit).

My function is close to empty. I have tried several things but nothing works.
I think I should somehow use this:

```
Person* PersonReg::SearchForPerson(std::string search, Person *person)
{
   std::string s1 = search;

   size_t foundName = s1.find(person->name);
   size_t foundAddress = s1.find(person->adress);

   if( /*hit*/)
   {
      //Print out FOUND
      return person;
   }
   else
   {
     return nullptr;
   }
}
```

My constructor to Person:

```
Person::Person(std::string _name, std::string _adress)
{
    this->name = _name;
    this->adress = _adress;
}
```

Anyone with an idea on how to continue this?

[EDIT]

I didnt show how i Stored my Persons, here it is:  (PersonReg.cpp)

```
PersonReg::PersonReg(const int _maxSize)
{
    this->maxSize = _maxSize;
    personArray = new Person[_maxSize];
}

void PersonReg::AddPerson(Person *person)
{
    this->personArray[indexInt++] = *person;
}
```

Comment: I am not completely sure about what exact datastructure you are using to store multiple Person objects and what if two persons share same name? But you may try to see if **find_if** C++ algorithm library function is useful for your purpose. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/

Comment: I've added it now, appreciate the feedback! I was not sure how much of the code I needed to show.

Comment: Write two functions; one to search for a name, one to search for an address. Neither needs a `Person*` parameter. It should search through `personArray` for a person with the specified name or address.

Comment: To be clear: you're going in a wrong direction and should not continue, but start over. If you have a list of names and addresses on a piece of paper, in no particular order, how do you find the person with a particular name? Scan down the page until you find that name, right? So do that, but in C++, where `personArray` is your "paper" and a loop is your "scanner".